# Handling a button press in Telegram Bot API

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am using **telebot** (Telegram Bot API) to program my telegram bot. I have a button and I want to send back a certain message to a user, who presses this button. I implement this by using callback query handler decorator:

```
@tb.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True if button.callback_data else False)
def iq_callback(query):
    tb.answer_callback_query(query.id)
    tb.send_message(query.message.chat.id, 'hi there')
```

Is this the correct way to handle button clicks in telebot or there is an easier way?